# Count return wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL query:

```
function players_check() {
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`player_id`) FROM `players` WHERE `user_id`=".$_SESSION['user_id']);
    if ($result3 <= 25) {
        fill_team();
    } else {
        echo 'something else';
    }
}
```

The issue with it is the fact that despite the fact that there are over 25 (by a long way in testing at times) results, it does not stop and echo, instead it carries on adding more and more.  The fill_team() function looks like so:

```
function fill_team() {
    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= 25) {
        $first_name = first_name();
        $last_name = second_name();
        echo "<br>";
        $add_names = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `players` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `user_id`) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name',  '{$_SESSION['user_id']}')");
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I've tried playing with the numbers but it doesn't seem to make too much of a difference.  I know it's a bit of a unique question but any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have not fetched a row.  `$result3` is a MySQL result resource, _not_ the scalar result of your query. You must first `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result3);` Then your value will be present in `$row[0]`

Comment: Mysql_query returns a resource, not a value

Comment: This looks like something specific to your actual code, but you're not adding a `player_id` when you're calling your `fill_team()` function. You will likely have a lot of records with `NULL` or whatever the default for the table is.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I think `player_id` is the primary key of table `players`

Answer (score 2):

`$result3` is a Mysql result resource and not the count result. The row containing the counted value must be fetched before it can be accessed.

```
function players_check() {
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`player_id`) FROM `players` WHERE `user_id`=".$_SESSION['user_id']);
    $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3); // fetch the row
    if ($res[0] <= 25){ // compare the counted value
        fill_team();
    } else {
        echo 'something else';
    }
}
```